# How to display NumPad keys to user

Tags: terminology, copywriting, windows-os

We are trying to map how a user will see key presses for custom hotkeys. However, there is some debate which I cannot find a standard for:

How to display the number pad keys:

- num1, num2, numPLUS, etc
- 1(NUMPAD), 2(NUMPAD), PLUS(NUMPAD)
- ???

I prefer the second option as all caps is being used for all other keys, and the NUMPAD is easier to understand than `num`

So, I am taking the discussion here. Is there a standard I am missing?

**FURTHER ELABORATION**

We have a hotkey UI that shows the user the keypress actions that will occur:

ie. When they press Shift and 7 we display "SHIFT + 7"

But, the number pad keys on a keyboard are mapped to a different keycode, so we cannot tell the user that if they press the `7` on the numberpad that it is `SHIFT + 7`, because in reality it is `SHIFT + 7 (NUMPAD)`

Comment: Can you elaborate, I cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @rk. Added, let me know if that helps clarify

Comment: Do you mean something like: "How do you refer to the number-pad keys in a way that users understand?". It's a terminology thing really.

Comment: @JonW Yes, it is mostly a terminology thing. But, also a consistency thing. If we go with all caps for everything, then going with lowercase num to display a difference in key location does not seem valid to me.

Comment: Just as a datapoint, XWindows calls them `KP_1` etc., but I agree that a user would be more familiar with "number pad" than "keypad".

Comment: Distinguishing between numpad numbers and typewriter key numbers is going to be confusing.  If you could have both sets of number keys have the same semantics it would be less confusing.

Comment: +1 @obelia. I'm not sure if having a numpad number and a typewriter number have different functions is such a good idea.

Comment: @obelia Gray, this is just using a windows hook, so these come across as different keys codes. We will discuss creating an intercepter that will map them as one, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using acronyms or using titles, I would **advice against the use of all upper case words**. Look at the keyboard shortcut listings from [Apple (OSX)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) and [Windows (8)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/new-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=t1).

I agree with your argument that **numpad is easier to understand than num**, it reduces the mental step of mapping num acronym to its full word.

`Shift + 7(Numpad)`

---

Also, if the keyboard has a **symbol** associated with the numpad then you can consider using that. 
[image]

You can make a **legend for your own shortcuts**, `Num` for `Numpad` and then use the shorthand notation. `Num7`

Comment: Thanks, we came to the same conclusion on Numpad. I will pass on the advice on uppercase and leave it to our designer along those lines

Comment: Also, I cant edit your answer, but you have a rather unfortunate misspelling in your Shift+7 that needs fixed :)

Comment: @JustinPihony That's what the user said ;)